# Effective for loop in assembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, assembly, for-loop

Im currently trying to get used to assembler and I have written a for loop in c++ and then I have looked at it in disassembly. I was wondering if anyone could explain to me what each step does and/or how to improve the loop manually.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
     013A17AE  mov         dword ptr [i],0  
     013A17B5  jmp         encrypt_chars+30h (13A17C0h)  
     013A17B7  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  
     013A17BA  add         eax,1  
     013A17BD  mov         dword ptr [i],eax  
     013A17C0  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  
     013A17C3  cmp         eax,dword ptr [length]  
     013A17C6  jge         encrypt_chars+6Bh (13A17FBh)  
temp_char = OChars [i];         // get next char from original string
     013A17C8  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  
     013A17CB  mov         cl,byte ptr OChars (13AB138h)[eax]  
     013A17D1  mov         byte ptr [temp_char],cl
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @John please use the "edit" link below the tags to add information to the question. I did this for you this time.

Comment: Any improvements in efficiency, for example using less lines of codes etc but the main thing im after is understanding how it works. Thanks.

Comment: You can't just "improve" the loop.  It has to be improved on a case-by-case basis.  The basic loop is already optimized by the compiler.  If you want help improving it more you'll have to give more context.

Comment: Sorry I didnt realise, im currently studying at university and an extension task is to try optimize the code. I wasnt aware it couldnt be improved any further, thank you for your reply.

Comment: The code is incomplete (what is going on between 013A17C6 and 13A17FB) entire loop body is missing. How it works? Assembly is absolutely clear here - looks like you compiled it in DEBUG mode.

Comment: This snippet very obviously came from a Debug build. It's debugger-friendly and therefore utterly unoptimized. Improving *this code* is possible - but the compiler will be able to do it much better. Just perform a Release build.

Comment: Still incomplete. 0x2B bytes more - up to address 13A17FB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd note that what you've posted seems to contain only part of the loop body. Second, it looks like you compiled with *all* optimization turned off -- when/if you turn on optimization, don't be surprised if the result looks rather different.

That said, let's look at the code line-by-line:

```
 013A17AE mov dword ptr [i],0
```

This is basically just `i=0`.

```
 013A17B5 jmp encrypt_chars+30h (13A17C0h)
```

This is going to the beginning of the loop. Although it's common to put the test at the top of a loop in most higher level languages, that's not always the case in assembly language.

```
 013A17B7 mov eax,dword ptr [i]
 013A17BA add eax,1
 013A17BD mov dword ptr [i],eax
```

This is `i++` in (extremely sub-optimal) assembly language. It's retrieving the current value of `i`, adding one to it, then storing the result back into `i`.

```
 013A17C0 mov eax,dword ptr [i]
 013A17C3 cmp eax,dword ptr [length]
 013A17C6 jge encrypt_chars+6Bh (13A17FBh)
```

This is basically `if (i==length) /* skip forward to some code you haven't shown */` It's retrieving the value of `i` and comparing it to the value of `length`, the jumping somewhere if `i` was greater than or equal to `length`.

If you were writing this in assembly language by hand, you'd normally use something like `xor eax, eax` (or `sub eax, eax`) to zero a register. In most cases, you'd start from the maximum and count down to zero if possible (avoids a comparison in the loop). You certainly wouldn't store a value into a variable, then immediately retrieve it back out (in fairness, a compiler probably won't do that either, if you turn on optimization).

Applying that, and moving the "variables" into registers, we'd end up with something on this general order:

```
    mov ecx, length
loop_top:
    ; stuff that wasn't pasted goes here
    dec ecx
    jnz loop_top
```

Comment: Sorry my edit didn't paste all of the code, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to interpret this in plain english:

```
 013A17AE  mov         dword ptr [i],0               ; Move into i, 0
 013A17B5  jmp         encrypt_chars+30h (13A17C0h)  ; Jump to check
 013A17B7  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]             ; Load i into the accumulator (register eax)
 013A17BA  add         eax,1                         ; Increment the accumulator
 013A17BD  mov         dword ptr [i],eax             ; and put that in it, effectively adding
; 1 to i.
check:
 013A17C0  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]             ; Move i into the accumulator
 013A17C3  cmp         eax,dword ptr [length]        ; Compare it to the value in 'length',
; setting flags
 013A17C6  jge         encrypt_chars+6Bh (13A17FBh)  ; Jump if it's greater or equal. This
; address is not in your code snippet
```

The compiler preferes EAX for arithmetic.  Each register (in the past, I don't know if this is still current) has some type of operation that it is faster at doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the part that should be more optimized:
(note: your compiler ***SHOULD*** do this, so either you have optimizations turned off, or something in the loop body is preventing this optimization)

```
mov eax,dword ptr [i]    ; Go get "i" from memory, put it in register EAX
add eax,1                ; Add one to register EAX
mov dword ptr [i],eax    ; Put register EAX back in memory "i". (now one bigger)
mov eax,dword ptr [i]    ; Go get "i" from memory, put it in EAX again.
```

See how often you're moving values back-n-forth from memory to EAX?

You should be able to load "i" into EAX once at the beginning of the loop, run the full loop directly out of EAX, and put the finished value back into "i" after its all done.
(unless something else in your code prevents this)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, this code comes from DEBUG build. It ***is*** possible to optimize it, but MS compiler produces very good code for such simple cases.

There is no point to do it manually, just re-build it in release mode and read the listing to learn how to do it.